# can I run Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell R410

Tags: server, 20.04, updates, 22.04

I have a somewhat older server (Dell R410) that runs Ubuntu 20.04

I've been wanting to run some software that requires 22.04, and I like to have my things up to date, it's not super important, but just a nice to have.
It shows a message to update to 22.04, but on another server I had before (HP DL380 G7)
it would not function while running a newer version than 18.04.
I don't exactly recall what didn't work but at least ethernet didn't work.
I want to make sure I won't have this problem again.

I am hosting some things that are not easy to replace, so I'd prefer to not have to re-install the server if it wouldn't work.

I'm wondering if it's safe for me to upgrade or if I should leave it at 20.04?
Or if there's a way for me to check if all the hardware is compatible?

Comment: The hardware is more than likely fine as Dells go through a remarkable amount of testing with each Ubuntu release. That said, there are quite a few software differences between 20.04 and 22.04, so you will want to *test* before pulling the trigger on an upgrade. Nobody here will know your entire software stack, so it will be impossible to state with authority that you are "safe". This aside, 20.04 is supported until 2025 and, if you subscribe for the extended maintenance, you're good until 2030. This should give you plenty of time to determine whether you are ready to upgrade 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @matigo thank you for your reply, this is very helpful thank you!

Comment: @karel not really, but kind of, it's not really what I hoped for, but I guess I do have to test it first, thank you for your reply.

Comment: this is off topic: What constitutes as "works" depends on what you call "works" so is an opinion. A tortoise moves with the speed of light from the viewpoint of a snail.

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource great:
https://ubuntu.com/certified/vendors/Dell%20Technologies

It at least tells you which release of Ubuntu that is certified on which Dell hardware.

But as stated in before, with old hardware and new OS one needs to try it out and find out what issues might occur. I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an old HP Proliant server and for what I'm doing with it (web server and such) it works great.

Try it out, that's the fun part any way isnt't it? :)

Comment: Old and obsolete. A hardware list is only valid for 1 HWE stack and needs to be reevaluated.

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, the question is about old and obsolete hardware. So to find out what it once were certified for is good information.